# Modulo seems to not be working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, modulo

I have simple select statement that uses 1 table. One of the columns take that value of the column, divides it, then does modulo after that but I end up with a decimal. Why is modulo not working?

```
SELECT
    (numeric_datatype_column / 10000) % 100
FROM 
    table a
```

All of my values are coming out as decimals. Shouldn't the modulo give me an integer?

Comment: Please show an example. I suspect that the module result is correct, it's jut that you're seeing .00000 after the integer part..

Comment: If the `numeric_datatype_column` has decimals, doing a mod will also return the decimals.  `Select (123.1234 / 10) % 100` yields `12.3123400`

Comment: Why do you expect it to be an integer? `5.1 % 2.5` returns `0.1`. This is the correct remainder after division.

Comment: If you want only whole number / integer remainders then you can use `select floor((numeric_datatype_column / 10000) % 100)`

Comment: Siyual, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Scsimon, thanks that actually is what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the modulo give me an integer?

No.  The [modulo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql) returns the *remainder* of the value after the division.  If your value is a decimal value, the modulo will also return the decimal component.  It is not truncated.

As a working example:

```
Select (123.1234 / 10) % 5
```

> 2.3123400

If you want to remove the decimals, you can convert the result to an `INT` and then do the modulo:

```
Select Convert(Int, (123.1234 / 10)) % 5
```

> 2